# Chrome Extension : Context menu check-box not visible in windows chrome browser version: 23.0.1271.91

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome Extension.
Created check-box with context-menu options, it's working fine in Chrome Browser(version 21.0.1180.15 beta) of Ubuntu(O/S).
But check-box is not visible in Windows-XP Chrome Browser (version 23.0.1271.91)

```
var contextMenuCallback = function(info, tab) {
  console.log(info);
  console.log(tab);
  // we can do other stuff here.
}

var first_params = {
  "id": "first_id",
  "title": "First",
  "type": "checkbox",
  "checked": true,
  "onclick": contextMenuCallback
};
var second_params = {
 "id": "second_id",
 "title": "Second",
 "type": "checkbox",
 "checked": true,
 "onclick": contextMenuCallback
};  
chrome.contextMenus.create(first_params);
chrome.contextMenus.create(second_params);
```

Give your suggestions for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on same version and it works

[image]

Have you checked permissions for context menu's as shown here.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Context Menu Demo",
  "description": "This gives demo of context menu features",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons":{"16":"screen.png","48":"screen.png","128":"screen.png"}
}
```

Have you included code in `background.js` as here

```
var contextMenuCallback = function(info, tab) {
  console.log(info);
  console.log(tab);
  // we can do other stuff here.
}

var first_params = {
  "id": "first_id",
  "title": "First",
  "type": "checkbox",
  "checked": true,
  "onclick": contextMenuCallback
};
var second_params = {
 "id": "second_id",
 "title": "Second",
 "type": "checkbox",
 "checked": true,
 "onclick": contextMenuCallback
};  
chrome.contextMenus.create(first_params);
chrome.contextMenus.create(second_params);
```

Try this code and send us screen shot for output what you are expecting and what is missing?

Comment: I was updating the context menu with checked=false, with this code : chrome.contextMenus.update("first_id", {"checked":false});

Comment: And now got the solution, need to code like this : chrome.contextMenus.update("first_id", {"type": "checkbox", "checked": false});